# Why is `service x11-common stop` timing out?

Tags: server, 15.04, xorg, init.d

Tried to install a package that had X11 as a dependency on a server (Installing erlang on Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid from DigitalOcean). It's not a production system, so wasn't too worried, but one or more of the packages failed to install.

Once I realised, I decided to uninstall the package and its dependencies, but x11-common and a couple of others failed to uninstall, because whenever it tried to do `service xxxxx stop`, it tells me that the connection timed out.

(Note: It's now fixed, see my answer below - but I'm still curious how this might happen)

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why this happened, but rebooting the machine seems to have fixed it - though `sudo reboot` wouldn't work, had to use DigitalOcean's power cycle feature. Is it possible that the init system changed as a dependency on my package?